# Weather data JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am currently working on a program that parses json data from an http request, and I seem to be running into the problem of the program not parsing the json correctly when used in succession. I have gone back and tried singular trials on successive trials that have failed and have found that they succeed in parsing the data correctly.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
{"latitude":-35.2809,"longitude":149.13,"timezone":"Australia/Sydney","offset":10,"hourly":{"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","data":[{"time":1492610400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":48.24,"apparentTemperature":48.24,"dewPoint":47.73,"humidity":0.98,"windSpeed":2.91,"windBearing":152,"visibility":5.65,"cloudCover":0.03,"pressure":1030},{"time":1492614000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":48.42,"apparentTemperature":48.42,"dewPoint":48.42,"humidity":1,"windSpeed":0,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1029.99},{"time":1492617600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":48.56,"apparentTemperature":47.7,"dewPoint":48.05,"humidity":0.98,"windSpeed":3.38,"windBearing":31,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1029.74},{"time":1492621200,"summary":"Foggy","icon":"fog","precipType":"rain","temperature":46.49,"apparentTemperature":46.49,"dewPoint":45.93,"humidity":0.98,"windSpeed":0.69,"windBearing":16,"visibility":0.59,"cloudCover":0.14,"pressure":1029.42},{"time":1492624800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":48.35,"apparentTemperature":46.51,"dewPoint":48.35,"humidity":1,"windSpeed":4.65,"windBearing":167,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1029.58},{"time":1492628400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":46.73,"apparentTemperature":46.73,"dewPoint":46.25,"humidity":0.98,"windSpeed":1.05,"windBearing":7,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1029.61},{"time":1492632000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":47.05,"apparentTemperature":47.05,"dewPoint":45.96,"humidity":0.96,"windSpeed":2.95,"windBearing":90,"visibility":5.61,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1029.93},{"time":1492635600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":49.93,"apparentTemperature":49.93,"dewPoint":49.93,"humidity":1,"windSpeed":2.86,"windBearing":90,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1030.28},{"time":1492639200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":52.4,"apparentTemperature":52.4,"dewPoint":51.47,"humidity":0.97,"windSpeed":2.32,"windBearing":101,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1030.84},{"time":1492642800,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipType":"rain","temperature":56.47,"apparentTemperature":56.47,"dewPoint":52.32,"humidity":0.86,"windSpeed":1.51,"windBearing":68,"visibility":5.25,"cloudCover":1,"pressure":1031.06},{"time":1492646400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":62.51,"apparentTemperature":62.51,"dewPoint":54.09,"humidity":0.74,"windSpeed":4.85,"windBearing":61,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1030.51},{"time":1492650000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":64.46,"apparentTemperature":64.46,"dewPoint":51.78,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":1.28,"windBearing":337,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1029.87},{"time":1492653600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":67.6,"apparentTemperature":67.6,"dewPoint":49.74,"humidity":0.53,"windSpeed":4.52,"windBearing":3,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1028.82},{"time":1492657200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":69.93,"apparentTemperature":69.93,"dewPoint":48.56,"humidity":0.47,"windSpeed":5.43,"windBearing":225,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1028.01},{"time":1492660800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":69.82,"apparentTemperature":69.82,"dewPoint":47.8,"humidity":0.46,"windSpeed":3.54,"windBearing":311,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1026.99},{"time":1492664400,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":69.81,"apparentTemperature":69.81,"dewPoint":46.36,"humidity":0.43,"windSpeed":5.82,"windBearing":350,"visibility":6.79,"cloudCover":0.31,"pressure":1026.38},{"time":1492668000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":69.72,"apparentTemperature":69.72,"dewPoint":48.89,"humidity":0.48,"windSpeed":5.73,"windBearing":265,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1026.34},{"time":1492671600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":64.75,"apparentTemperature":64.75,"dewPoint":47.57,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":3.76,"windBearing":307,"visibility":6.2,"pressure":1026.36},{"time":1492675200,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":57.57,"apparentTemperature":57.57,"dewPoint":48.9,"humidity":0.73,"windSpeed":4.49,"windBearing":67,"visibility":6.2,"cloudCover":0.31,"pressure":1026.83},{"time":1492678800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":62.72,"apparentTemperature":62.72,"dewPoint":48.74,"humidity":0.6,"windSpeed":8.12,"windBearing":77,"pressure":1027.15},{"time":1492682400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":54.89,"apparentTemperature":54.89,"dewPoint":46.81,"humidity":0.74,"windSpeed":2.82,"windBearing":84,"pressure":1027.33},{"time":1492686000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":54.22,"apparentTemperature":54.22,"dewPoint":47.43,"humidity":0.78,"windSpeed":1.91,"windBearing":63,"visibility":6.2,"cloudCover":0.02,"pressure":1027.75},{"time":1492689600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":54.21,"apparentTemperature":54.21,"dewPoint":48.32,"humidity":0.8,"windSpeed":1.51,"windBearing":190,"visibility":6.2,"cloudCover":0,"pressure":1027.64},{"time":1492693200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":52.26,"apparentTemperature":52.26,"dewPoint":47.73,"humidity":0.85,"windSpeed":2.65,"windBearing":81,"visibility":6.2,"cloudCover":0,"pressure":1027.49}]},"daily":{"data":[{"time":1492610400,"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","sunriseTime":1492633936,"sunsetTime":1492673690,"moonPhase":0.77,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":46.49,"temperatureMinTime":1492621200,"temperatureMax":69.93,"temperatureMaxTime":1492657200,"apparentTemperatureMin":46.49,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1492621200,"apparentTemperatureMax":69.93,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1492657200,"dewPoint":48.63,"humidity":0.77,"windSpeed":1.07,"windBearing":53,"visibility":5.88,"cloudCover":0.28,"pressure":1028.66}]}}
```

Here is the code:

```
def truncate(listName):
ret=listName[:len(listName)-1]
return(ret)


#init var
unixtime="11177678800"
timeW,bearingW,speedW,humidityW,dewptW,tempW=([] for i in range(6))
timeTmp,bearingTmp,speedTmp,humidityTmp,dewptTmp,tempTmp=([] for i in range(6))

#prepare data file
if(os.path.exists('weatherData.txt')):
    with open('weatherData.txt', 'r') as f:
        txtData = f.readlines()
        for line in txtData:
            if "time" in line:
                timeW += re.findall(r'\d+', line[6:])
            elif "windBearing" in line:
                bearingW += re.findall(r'\d+', line[12:])
            elif "windSpeed" in line:
                speedW += re.findall(r'\d+.\d+', line[10:])
            elif "humidity" in line:
                humidityW += re.findall(r'\d+.\d+', line[10:])
            elif "dewpt" in line:
                dewptW = re.findall(r'\d+.\d+', line[6:])
            elif "temp" in line:
                tempW = re.findall(r'\d+.\d+', line[5:])
    os.remove('weatherData.txt')

for i in range(10):
    print("parsing")
    url ="https://api.darksky.net/forecast/47c7da943ef96bcbe26ddf4ac4f885bd/-35.2809,149.13,{0}?exclude=currently%2Cflags".format(unixtime)
    print(url)
    data = str(*urllib.request.urlopen(url))
    timeTmp = re.findall(r'(?<=time":)\d+',data)
    bearingTmp = re.findall(r'(?<=windBearing":)\d+', data)
    speedTmp = re.findall(r'(?<=windSpeed":)(\d+.?\d+|\d+)', data)
    humidityTmp = re.findall(r'(?<=humidity":)(\d+.?\d+|\d+)', data)
    dewptTmp = re.findall(r'(?<=dewPoint":)(\d+.?\d+|\d+)', data)
    tempTmp = re.findall(r'(?<=temperature":)(\d+.?\d+|\d+)', data)
    timeTmp = truncate(timeTmp)
    bearingTmp = truncate(bearingTmp)
    speedTmp = truncate(speedTmp)
    humidityTmp = truncate(humidityTmp)
    dewptTmp = truncate(dewptTmp)
    maxTime=int(max(timeTmp))
    unixtime = str(maxTime + 4000)
```

Comment: That's a lot more than a sample of data. Where's the error in the code?

Comment: Please try using the `json` module... You're making that parsing a lot more complex than necessary

Comment: it's too few characters for me to suggest the edit, but your `def truncate` is indented wrong here - also list_name = list_name[:-1] does the same thing. In answer to your question you should probably use the json module as suggested, or else look at pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: For God's sake, use the `json` module - or even better here, use `python-requests` and then the  `response.json()` method.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, i was not aware of the json module as this is the first time I've ever dealt with json data in python. I will give this a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex, use either `json` or `jsontree` module to load the data.

```
import json
import requests
with open('weatherData.txt', 'r') as f:
   weather = json.loads(f)

latitude = weather['latitude']
hour_summary = weather['hourly']['summary']
daily_icon = weather['daily']['data'][0]['icon']
.....
```

jsontree will convert elements to notation. However, it doesn't support Python3.

The build in urllib modules is pretty cumbersome, use `requests` package, e.g.

```
import requests
response = requests(url)
data = response.json()
#Just use the typical python dict traverse method as shown in above code.
```